# Make copy a vs application project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I created a web application project and it's working fine. Now I copy this project and create the new project with the same source. This is also working fine. Now I'll try to publish the second project now I get the error:

```
Copying file obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Site.Master to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Site.Master failed. Could not find file 'obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Site.Master'
```

I tried many way, but not resolved my problem. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like VS is telling you it can't find the file Site.Master. Check that it (and any others) is included in the project by:

- Click the "Show all files" icon in the Solution Explorer. This will show if any files are not included in the project;
- The right click on the files/folders that are greyed out (not included)
- Select "Include in project".